# Which count max char in UITextField and UITextView

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview

Which count maximum char's in `UITextField` and `UITextView`? It is really interesting for me! I have some `textfields` and `textviews`. And if I don't set max value for it, then which count char's can be in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement **`UITextFieldDelegate`** and **`UITextViewDelegate`**  Method to get the count of characters

Try this code

**For UITextView's**

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    NSUInteger enteredTextLength; // Variable to store the length on entered string.

    if(textView == txtViewName) {
        enteredTextLength = [textView.text length] + [text length] - range.length;

        NSLog(@"Text Length = %d", enteredTextLength);

        // To check number of characters entered.
        if (enteredTextLength < 10) {
            return YES;
        }
        else {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

**For UITextField's**

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSUInteger enteredTextLength; // Variable to store the length on entered string.

    if(textField == txtAlpha) {
        enteredTextLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;

        NSLog(@"Text Length = %d", enteredTextLength);

        // To check number of characters entered.
        if (enteredTextLength < 10) {
            return YES;
        }
        else {
            return NO;
        }

    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want know which max count char's can be in uitextfield. I.e. which maximum length of the string. I know how I can limit it. Sorry, if you can't understand me.

Comment: @alex_izh Could you please explain me what exactly you mean **which max count char's can be in uitextfield**

Comment: I mean, if I will insert 1 million symbols to uitextfield every 10 seconds, when it stops working and what will happen in this case

Comment: @alex_izh by the way why do you want that?